# Finding k for the homogenenous equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi i'm having trouble finding k here.

I know that a first solution to the equation

$xy''-2(x+1)y'+(x+2)y=x^3e^{2x}, x>0$  is of the form $y_1=e^{kx}$ for some k.

I have tried using the Euler-Cauchy technique as in trying $y=x^k$ and differentiating respectively but did not seem to work.

ps i should not use the Laplace transformation here as far as i know

A hint would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Plugging $y=e^{kx}$ in the homogeneous equation we get
$$
k^2\,x-2\,k\,(x+1)+x+2=0.
$$
For this to hold we must have $k=1$. So $y_1(x)=e^x$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation. To find a second one (by reduction of order) let $y_2(x)=e^x\,u(x)$. Once you find $y_2$, use the method of variation of constants to find a particular solution of the complete equation.

Comment: Thank you julian, i'd made a small mistake regarding the derivatives of $e^x$ and hence my confusion but yeah does work